# Scrollable view passing behind another scrollable view

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a layout where I have two scroll views, one is a `PageView` which is used to display a list of pictures horizontally, the second is a `SingleChildScrollView` (maybe should be something else?), this scroll view is partially above the first one as initial position and can go completely over. Some screenshots to image this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The problem is, if I make the 2nd scroll view take all page and add internal padding to it to make it the good height, the 2nd scroll view work as expected but the first one (witch is behind) isn't working anymore. The 2nd solution would be to wrap the `SingleChildScrollView` with a `Padding` widget to make it the good height and add `Clip.none` parameter to the scroll view, but in this case the scroll view cannot be scrolled in `PageView` zone even if the `SingleChildScrollView`is over.

I wonder if someone already encountered a behavior like this and what is your solution.

Here my actual code with second solution:

```
  Widget body() {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, boxConstraints) {
        this.boxConstraints = boxConstraints;
        uiHeight = boxConstraints.maxHeight -
            boxConstraints.maxWidth * 9 / 16 +
            scrollableUIBorderRadius;
        return Stack(
          children: [
            coverWidget(),
            scrollableUI(),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget coverWidget() { //This is the PageView containing pictures
    return Positioned.fill(
        bottom: uiHeight - scrollableUIBorderRadius,
        child: global.coverWidget(
          placeId: widget.place.id,
          galleryItemsLinks: widget.galleryItemsLinks!,
          initialIndex: widget.coverIndex,
          onIndexUpdate: widget.onUpdateIndex,
          circleIndicatorsDistanceFromBottom:
              (boxConstraints.maxHeight - uiHeight) / 15 +
                  scrollableUIBorderRadius,
        ));
  }

  Widget scrollableUI() {
    return Positioned.fill(
      top: boxConstraints.maxHeight - uiHeight,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        controller: _scrollController,
        physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(parent: BouncingScrollPhysics()),
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: uiHeight * 2,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned.fill(
                child: global.containerWidget(
                  placeId: widget.place.id,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(scrollableUIBorderRadius),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(scrollableUIBorderRadius)),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

NB: if possible I want to conserve those `BouncingScrollPhysics` easily so a solution with `AnimationBuilder` && `Transform` && `GestureDetector`is the last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a little hack to do this, I passed the `PageView` containing the photos inside the the `SingleChildScrollView` so the `PageView` is on top and can receive touch events, to keep the `PageView` fixed to the top of the screen I use a `Transform` widget that reverse the `scrollOffset` of the `SingleChildScrollView`.

###### My implementation:

(here the `Transform` widget is also used to resize the `PageView` containing photos when the `scrollOffset` is under 0)

```
[...]

late ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController()
    ..addListener(_scrollListener);
double _scrollOffset = 0.0;

[...]

_scrollListener() {
    setState(() {
      _scrollOffset = _scrollController.offset;
    });
}

[...]

Widget body() {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, boxConstraints) {
      this.boxConstraints = boxConstraints;
      coverHeight = boxConstraints.maxWidth * 9 / 16;
      return SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(parent: BouncingScrollPhysics()),
        controller: _scrollController,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Transform(
              transform: Matrix4.compose(
                  vector.Vector3(
                      _scrollOffset > 0 ? 0 : _scrollOffset, _scrollOffset, 0),
                  vector.Quaternion.euler(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                  vector.Vector3(
                      _scrollOffset > 0
                          ? 1.0
                          : 1.0 - _scrollOffset / boxConstraints.maxHeight * 4,
                      _scrollOffset > 0
                          ? 1.0
                          : 1.0 - _scrollOffset / boxConstraints.maxHeight * 4,
                      1.0)),
              child: SizedBox(
                height: coverHeight,
                child: global.coverWidget(
                  placeId: widget.place.id,
                  galleryItemsLinks: widget.galleryItemsLinks!,
                  initialIndex: widget.coverIndex,
                  onIndexUpdate: widget.onUpdateIndex,
                  circleIndicatorsDistanceFromBottom:
                      coverHeight / 15 + scrollableUIBorderRadius,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Stack(
              clipBehavior: Clip.none,
              children: [
                Positioned.fill(
                  top: -scrollableUIBorderRadius,
                  child: global.containerWidget(
                    placeId: widget.place.id,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(scrollableUIBorderRadius),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(scrollableUIBorderRadius)),
                  ),
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    [...]
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```

Comment: Self answering is a bit hacky since it's aiming for granting scores...

Comment: @egor518 Can you please explain what you mean by that? I'm not earning anything by self answering my question. The goal here is that future developers who have the same problem will be able to resolve it with the help of this answer, no matter if it's mine or someone else... If you have a better answer you are free to post it here and I'm sure I will enjoy it.